# Is MSE an appropriate place to post questions about translations/localization issues for mod related features?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, meta, scope, localization

Is MSE an appropriate place to post questions about translations/localization issues for mod related features?

If not, where should I do that?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, in general, Meta.SE is an appropriate place to post bug reports, feature requests, and discussions about moderator tools. Localization is on-topic as well, as you're well familiar with :)

The exception is when **the post would be about tools that are not public knowledge**. Posts about those, including about localization, **do *not* belong on Meta.SE**, and instead should be directed towards the private [Stack Moderators Team](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/moderators/questions).

This generally includes tools such as those used to detect sockpuppets and voting fraud. If in doubt about whether or not the tool is public knowledge, err on the side of caution and use the Team; staff monitors posts there (especially if you use the [needs-staff](/questions/tagged/needs-staff) tag). You can also ask in the [TL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/teachers-lounge/info) about specific tools before posting anywhere.

Comment: Is there a list of **public knowledge mod tools**?